# Does ATX specify the load currents?

Tags: power-supply, atx

I find it difficult to see the elecrtical specs of ATX PSU. You can, for instance, have [this cheap block](http://www.spire-corp.com/power-supplies/pearl-600-sp-atx-600z-ppfc/) or [another one](http://ibox.pl/en/cases-power-supplies/1697-cube-2-600.html) but their homepages just say that PSUs are ATX-2.2/2.31 compliant and I see no min/max currents they give me on their rails. What does it mean? Probably I have a duplicate of [current distribution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234127/atx-power-supply-typical-load-distribution) but I want to put the question squarely.

Comment: Actually, the stickers on the PSUs specify the maximum load currents, but usually the exact definitions of "maximum" are not very clear. Unfortunately, the products you mentioned do not have readable stickers on their photos.

Comment: I would **not** even consider these cheap PSUs. PSUs from a decent brand are not that more expensive and a decent brand will specify the max. current loads on the power rails. The ATX specification only describes the behavior of the supply (power good signal etc), type of connectors, pinouts. The ATX spec. only specifies the **minimum** current drive capability of the supply as far as I know. If you want to know what the ATX spec. means precisely, then read it but I warn you that's it is very technical. Written by EEs for EEs.

Answer (score 0):

The power or current ratings on ATX PSUs are maximum values. They show the max. available power at 12V, 5V, 3.3V and so on. Of course, lower loads and currents are allowed. Also your computer does not always use the full specified power. However, a small load on the output of switching power supply is always helpful for more exact regulation. A few mA should be sufficient. If you do not have very light loads or don't need precise regulation, there are no further steps necessary.

Advice: Check the ATX plug specification to turn an ATX PSU on. In general you have to connect the green wire of the 20/24 pin ATX plug to Ground.